# Finding width of text

Tags: c++, winapi

I am setting the font for a control like this:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
int lfHeight = -MulDiv(szFont, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
HFONT font = CreateFont(lfHeight, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, Font.c_str());
SendMessage(hwnd,WM_SETFONT,(WPARAM)font,0);
```

The control is a static. How would I find the width of the text in the static for a given string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28VS.85%29.aspx). You'll need to select the font into the DC first.

Comment: Should I select the font into the DC I got through `GetDC(NULL);` and then also pass that DC to the function? I'll try that.

Comment: @Alexander, If you are doing this some time after the initialization code you show in the question, use GetWindowDC using the HWND of the control.

Comment: Ah, well I just recreated the DC and the HFONT in the width check. It works well, thankyou for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

CDC::GetTextExtent() and CDC::GetOutputTextExtent() should help.

Comment: I didn't see MFC in the tags.